# Failed to deserialize input json to list<string> in MVC-API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a mvc web api via asp.net core. But found it is weird that can't deserialize the json body in request.

The target object as below

```
public class Status
{
    public string Content {get; set;}
    public string Publisher {get; set;}
    public List<string> Tags {get; set;} 
}
```

The json posted in request is like this:

```
{
    "content":"this is my baby dog",
    "publisher":"someone"
    "tags":[ "tag1", "tag2" ]
}
```

The api method in controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Publish([FromBody] Status status)
{
    // status should be deserialized now
}
```

When testing, the status is always null. But if I post a json without tags list, the status can be deserialized successfully. So seems like the failure reason here is caused by List. But it should be able to deserialized without any special configuration, right?

Comment: How are you post the json? Could you show the code?

Comment: provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your issue. confirm that the invalid json in post is not just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope that the issue is with the JSON data that you are passing, forgive me if it is a typo in the post. You missed a comma `,` before `"tags"` and that makes the JSON invalid.

Fix:

```
{
    "content":"this is my baby dog",
    "publisher":"someone",
    "tags":[ "tag1", "tag2" ]
}
```

Comment: You are right! I have kept testing around but didn't notice that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help you as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "content":"this is my baby dog",
    "publisher":"someone",
   "tags":[ {"tag1":"tag1"}, {"tag2":"tag2"}  ]
}
```

Comment: It would help if you will include some explanation to your answer. Thanks!